# Delete rows stepping over those that don't fulfill referential integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am not managing to find this on Google.

I am deleting rows from a table without checking if some could not be removed due to referential integrity. My idea is to remove those that fulfill it. I am using exactly the query "delete from member_companies" .

SQL Server 2008 R2 that I am using, though, cancels all the deletions if a row failing for referential integrity is found.

Is there some directive I could use to instruct it to remove rows that are possible to be removed? Or am I missing some other aspect of the story?

Comment: i think the pattern would be to make this a cursor, then loop over each row issuing a delete, then ignore the ones with the exceptions.

Comment: Please post your schema, sample data, and what you're trying to delete.  This might be able to be accomplished just with some joins and or not ins...

Comment: I did exactly that. The problem is that table contains a lot of rows, and the rows removal trigger cascade deletions, so the query generally  last very long. I am looking for a standard query alternative that should last shorter

Comment: Here I have 2 tables related: member_companies with company_id and the rest of company data, and users table that has regular user data (user_id, username, ..) plus company_id for which it has a foreign key relation linking to member_companies. I would like to delete companies that have no users associated with them. I know how to do it with cursors or even just joins, I just wondered if there is a directive in sql that says 'delete rows that fulfill referential integrity'

Comment: This question was pure curiosity, I think I have even found the solution for what I replied to Randy

Answer (score 0):

The rows not matching referential integrity must have been loaded either when the "WITH NOCHECK" option was used on the constraint, or you've used bulk insert or before the (referential) constraint was created.
 Aside from trying to re-apply the "WITH NOCHECK" option (might work), you'll probably need to just delete those rows that have a matching row in the other table(s) something like:

delete D
from member_companies D
where exists(select NULL from companies C where D.Comany_ID = C.ID)

This can be extended to multiple related tables. And, no it shouldn't be slow because EXISTS / NOT EXISTS should translate to a semi-join or anti-semi-join respectively (i.e. not a correlated sub-query) and better than a cursor.

Example for use on an AdventureWorks sample database:

--This sample removes those rows don’t fulfil the constraint, to reverse it remove the NOT.
begin tran
delete D
from Person.StateProvince D
where NOT EXISTS(select NULL from Person.Address C WHERE D.StateProvinceID = C.StateProvinceID)
AND NOT EXISTS(select NULL from Sales.SalesTaxRate C WHERE D.StateProvinceID = C.StateProvinceID)
rollback

Comment: I think we misunderstood here a bit - there is no table data that breaks referential integrity, the state is consistent. I was wondering only if there is a directive that will instruct the server to delete rows, on simple simple delete from table_name query, whose removal won't break referential integrity rules. Suppose there are not cascade deletes set for this.  I think, though, that the last section of your answer is one more solution for the problem.

Comment: I was just wondering if there exists a directive with which I can call "DELETE FROM MEMBER_COMPANIES STEP_OVER_ROWS_WHOSE_REMOVAL_WILL_BREAK_REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY" and expect to get the result.

Comment: There is no directive to do that. Only NOCHECK, which applies to the constraint when you create it, leaving any existing data that might break the new (referential integrity) constraint. You could of course drop and re-create the  (referential integrity) constraint. Finally, the AdventureWorks sample I gave removes only the "surplus" rows, i.e. those that won't break any of the inetgrity constraints on Person.StateProvince.

Comment: P.S. You can also use LEFT JOIN A ... WHERE A.ID IS NULL or other equivalent solutions (as in Answer 2) such WHERE NOT IN (....). But, they all have performance and or logic traps (LEFT JOIN needs care with the ON clause and NOT IN can break with NULLs in the list). EXISTS / NOT EXISTS just works well and avoids ALL of those problems.

Comment: Hey, when you mentioned that, why is NOT IN breaking when null is in the list? Tries to do regular comparison of column with null?

Comment: IN is basically a series of OR statements. NOT IN is "NOT(A OR B OR C)", applying De Morgans law you get "NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C". As a NULL in a comparison doesn't even match a NULL or a "NOT NULL", if any one of the comparisons has a NULL value - they ALL fail for the NOT IN. Well known logic problem. Seen that and careless "LEFT JOIN ON" usage create problem after problem in SQL. The "LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL" syntax does work, but you can have maintenace issues and more often still perfomance problems.

Comment: EXISTS not as widely used as it should be, too many myths about "it does correlated sub-queries". Finally, just as SELECT, FROM and JOIN are decendants of Relational Algebra (see books by EF Codd / CJ Date), EXISTS / NOT EXISTS have their roots in Relational Calculus. In summary EXISTS is fundamental to a really grasp of SQL, rather than an obscure "bolt-on".

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to find your rows to delete, and then delete them. Something like;

```
;WITH RowsToDelete AS (
 SELECT comp_id from member_companies mc 
 LEFT JOIN users u on u.comp_id = mc.comp_id 
 WHERE u.comp_id IS NULL
) 
DELETE 
  FROM member_companies 
 WHERE comp_id IN 
(Select comp_id FROM RowsToDelete)
```